# Javascript - Logical Or ||

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

I thought I know what is and how to use `||` ("Logical Or"), until seeing something.

This is what I understand:

```
if(conditional A || conditional B) {
    // execute if either A or B is true
}
```

This is what I don't, would you please explain.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var inBetween = false;

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(i == 1 || i == 3) {
     inBetween = !inBetween;
    }
    if(inBetween) {
        inputs[i].checked = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox">ONE</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">TWO</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">THREE</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">FOUR</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">FIVE</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">SIX</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">SEVEN</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">EIGHT</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">NINE</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">TEN</li>
</ul>
```

I thought either one of the coniditon is true, either `i == 1` or `i == 3`, the code within the if block will be executed. But then how come a bunch of inputs get involved? (in this case 1-3 were involved).

Why it is involving a range 1-3, but not just 1 or 1&3?

Why replacing `!inBetween` by `true` within the first `if` clause doesn't work?

Sorry for asking a very very basic question. But I really can't figure it out.

The codes were simplified from Javascript30: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIPYsKx1iiU

Comment: Because you're using the same `inBetween` variable. Once i is 1, `inBetween` becomes true. It *stays* true until `inBetween` is 3 where it becomes false.

Comment: Just reset `inBetween = false;` inside second if block.

Comment: Thank you Li357, Hassan Imam

Comment: Sorry guys, a further quesion, base on the "structure" of the above code, I changed the value from boolean to string, but the result isn't the same. After matching the second part of the if and ||, the value of the var changed forever, that's not the same as the above one, would you please help again?

    var myVar = 'a';
    for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
     if(i==3 || i==6){
      myVar = 'b';
     }
     console.log(i+' ' + myVar);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Li357 said, the `||` operator's logic is as you understand it. What is happening is the `inBetween` flag is being switched to `true` after `i == 1`. And the `inBetween` flag isnt being changed until `i == 3`, thus triggering your second `if` statement `if(inBetween)`.

If you switch your flag `inBetween` at the start if each loop this will fix your issue.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    inBetween = false;
    if(i == 1 || i == 3) {
        inBetween = true;
    }
    if(inBetween) {
        inputs[i].checked = true;
    }
}
```